# Get the error of a JSON Validation List in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, api, response

On my api test, it was able to run as the image below. but, when I try to code in React.JS, the user Id cannot be pass in. What is the problem of this?

[image]

But when I try to code in front end, the user Id cannot be pass in to api.
Consider the code below:

```
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    const Users_id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    this.state ={
      users_id: Users_id,
      event_name: '',
      event_email: '',
      event_description: '',
      event_type: '',
      event_location: '',
      start_date: '',
      end_date: '',
      history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  create(){
    // const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
    const Users_id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    this.setState({Users_id})
    // console.log(loginEmail)
    PostData('api/event/submit', this.state).then ((result) => {
        let responseJSON = result;
        console.log(responseJSON);
        console.log(this.state)

      });
   }
```

The error show in console.log(responseJSON):
[image]

//Updated PostData

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch( BaseUrl+type, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(userData),
            Accept: 'application/json',
            // mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: 
                { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },
          })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            resolve(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })

    });
```

Comment: is your API expecting users_id to be a number? or stringified number?

Comment: @Jacob ya, users_id is number.

Comment: I belive getItem returns a string. Try putting `console.log(typeof Users_id)` just before updating state.

Comment: Can you show the code for your PostData method?

Comment: @Jacob You're right, the response from console log is string. So is it any way to convert string to number?

Comment: `parseInt(Users_id)` or I guess `const Users_id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id'));`

Comment: @LydiaHendriks, Hi, sure. The PostData method was in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage.getItem returns a string. The id should be casted to a number

`const Users_id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id'));`

You may want to check `isNaN(Users_id)` before sending it. Or just let it fail, and handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if the user id exists in local storage before inserting it into props

```
    super(props);
    const Users_id = localStorage.getItem('id') || '';
    this.state ={
      users_id: Users_id,
      event_name: '',
      event_email: '',
      event_description: '',
      event_type: '',
      event_location: '',
      start_date: '',
      end_date: '',
      history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
```

and when you want to setState you need to pass the same name you used in the state

```
const Users_id = localStorage.getItem('id');
if(Users_id){
this.setState({users_id: Users_id})
}
```